# LINQ/Lambda equivalent to SQL NOT IN

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following:

```
context.tblProviderServices
.Where(ps => (DateTime.Now > ps.EffectiveDate && DateTime.Now < ps.TerminateDate) &&
         (ps.tblProvider.InactiveDate == null || DateTime.Now < ps.tblProvider.InactiveDate) &&
         (ps.tblProvider.IncludeInDirectory == "Y") &&
         (ps.ServiceStatusID == "Final") &&
         (ps.IsMemberSpecific == null || ps.IsMemberSpecific == false) &&
         (ps.tblProvider.tblProviderReferralHolds.Where(h => h.TerminateDate == null).Count() < 1))
```

and my question pertains to the last line.  That is wrong, I could tell as I was writing it but I can't seem to figure out how to change it to what I want.

All of these tables have proper relationships set up.  `tblProvider` is a 1 to Many with `tblProviderReferralHolds` and what I am trying to accomplish is limit my results to only Services whose Provider does not currently have a hold.

In SQL I could have accomplish something similar with a `NOT IN(SubQuery)` type deal.

How do I do this in LINQ?

Comment: I think that `IIterable` has a `Contains()` method, (but maybe that was just other collections that derived from it)

Comment: have you tried to use .Contains(), and negate it with ! ?

Comment: so `.Contains()` in place of the `.Where()`

Comment: maybe a `.Contains()` inside of your `.Where()`

Comment: so, `List1.Where(e -> List2.Contains(e))`

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972)

Last line would be

```
!(ps.tblProvider.tblProviderReferralHolds.Any(h => h.TerminateDate == null))
```

Comment: +1.  I see many developers use `Count` to accomplish the same thing.  But `Any` is the best for this, as it stops searching when it finds the first result that satisfies your condition.

Comment: These seems close but I have a question. The SQL in generates for just that part is --> (NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [dbo].[tblProviderReferralHold] AS [t4] WHERE ([t4].[TerminateDate] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[VendorID] = [t1].[VendorID]) AND ([t4].[ProviderID] = [t1].[ProviderID]) )) Looking at the SQL, isn't that wrong, the `SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]` part?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin - There's nothing wrong with doing `SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]`.  That'll still return rows, but won't select any real data from the table.  When you're just doing an `EXISTS` statement this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the linq "except".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx